# How to access a string in a struct of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, structure, multilingual

I have a structure:

```
struct dispPara
{   
    char *english,   
    char *french,
    void            *value;             
    unsigned char    type;          
    unsigned char    units;                 
};
```

and

```
struct dispPara dispParas[5] =
{

 {"abc_english", "xyz_frnch", &blah, blah, blah},

 {"english",  "frnch", &blah, blah, blah},

}
```

I am accessing english string with:  dispParas[i].english. Now, default is english string and if someone changes language to french, pointer should be printing french. how can I access french string with a pointer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you actually want. But if it is for internationalisation, you do it the wrong way, as you cannot index into a `struct`.

Instead, You should use a `const char *[]` per language (with all strings) and a `const char **` which points to the array for the current language.
The string would then be `current_language[text_index]`.

The arrays have to have the same meaning at the same index, of course. To be more clearly you should use an `enum` for each text instead of a numerical index:

```
const char *text_english[] = { "Hello", "World" };
const char *text_german[] = { "Hallo", "Welt" };

typedef enum {
    TEXT_HELLO = 0,
    TEXT_WORLD,
} TextCodes;

const char **current_language = text_english;

...

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s %s!", current_language[TEXT_HELLO], current_language[TEXT_WORLD]);
}
```

An alternative way would be to use a 2D array:

```
#define NUM_LANGUAGES 2

const char *text_strings[][NUM_LANGUAGES] = {
    { "Hello", "Hallo", },
    { "World", "Welt", },
};

...

size_t lang = 1; // german
printf("%s %s", text_strings[0][lang], text_strings[1][lang]);
```

The `enums` above can be used the same way. Problem here is that adding a new language will require to change the whole array instead of just adding a new one.

Comment: Olaf, Thank you for the response.

Comment: Olaf, Thank you for the response.  Currently, I am doing the same way you explained above but I was curious to know if it is possible to do the other way. I tried this way: 

int (*lang_ptr)[50] = dispParas[0].english  and 
++lang_ptr; 
and when a user changes the language to french: 
(*lang_ptr)[50] = dispParas[0].french. 
But it did not work properly. I don't know if it makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @Amar: It is more complicated, as you cannot index into a struct, so you need a switch to get the members. An alternative way I will add to my answer.

Comment: @Amar: I added an alternative way - yet still no struct (for reasons given).

Comment: I appreciate your response. Second solution looks better. Thanks.

Comment: @Amar: Depends. It does not allow to add/remove a langauge that easy like the first version does and is harder to let someone translate. Actually I use the first version (with an array for the languages), but generate it automatically (along with the `enum`s) with a Python program from another file.

Comment: const char *text_setting[] = {"one", "two",...};
const char *text_conf[] = {"done","wait",...};
const char *lang[] = {"Eng", "frn", "Germ"..};

const char **current_setting = text_setting;
const char **current_conf = text_conf;
const char **current_lang = lang;

how can I create an array (to index) of these double pointers,

char *multilingual[] =
{

     current_setting,
 current_conf,
 current_lang

};

am I doing it right?

it gives an error that initializer element is not constant.

Comment: @Amar: Pleas do not! I will not even try to read this. You can append this to your question (clearly mark this as an edit), but do not change the original contents! Actually you should do neither, just try and play a bit. Just be careful not to access an array out of bounds or with invalid type.